# How to set Content Type on HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Do you know how to set `Content-Type` on [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)?

Following code is on Blackberry and I want the Android equivalent:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "192.168.1.36"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");
```

Is it right for android?

Please advise.

Comment: Was looking for the right header to specify for a GET request, so got my question answered by looking at your question.

Comment: Hi, I have a question related to your topic... can you tell me some general idea on how "connection.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");" affects your procedure? Do you need like... wait for a 100 response, then do some other operation, and then wait for a 200 response?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you really want to use the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) you can use the [setRequestProperty](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method like:

```
myHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
myHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");
```

However, if I were you I'd look into using the [Apache HTTP libraries](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html). They're a little higher-level and easier to use. With them you would do it with something like:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.36/");
get.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
get.setHeader("Expect", "100-continue");

HttpResponse resp = null;
try {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    resp = httpClient.execute(get);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "HTTP protocol error", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Communication error", e);
}
if (resp != null) {
    // got a response, do something with it
} else {
    // there was a problem
}
```

Comment: Really as recommended you should use the UrlConnection as suggested by  Jesse Wilson - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: Note future people, @Chris.Jenkins is right. As of the time of this answer the apache libs were superior, but that changed in subsequent releases.

Comment: How can I send scope in http post method in java. I need to generate token by sending scope, id password and credentials. I am not able to get any code

Answer (score 16):

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "VALUE");
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

I have a question ? 

I am trying to create http GET connection : 

connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "192.168.1.36");
connection.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");

Is it right for android ?

Comment: Don't have much knowledge of android.

Also, See the comment on your ques.