# Get responsebody as characters

Tags: java

I am trying to get response from a website. I am using `HttpURLConnection` class.

this is my code:

```
        BufferedReader in = null;  
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream()));  
  String Line;

  while ((Line= in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(Line);
   }
```

All I get is :"�Q�u����0�_������q�J��R衔�J1�4q�Ȓ��d�%�ޑl/��^�0�ϯ�7�[6@~Ȟ�K��S��+u"

How can I decode it?
Thank you.

Comment: `new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream(), CHARSET_NAME)`

Comment: you should add some encoding : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945336/how-to-set-content-type-on-httpurlconnection

Comment: Which website, which page are you downloading from?

Answer (score 2):

The request is most likely GZipped.  Use a `GZIPInputStream` to read the request.

```
  BufferedReader in = null;  
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(httpCon.getInputStream())));  
  String Line;

  while ((Line= in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(Line);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! it was GZIPInputStream !

Comment: @user2126373 Excellent!  I had this same issue a few months back, I was glad I could pass this one on.  If that solved your issue could you please accept?  I'm one vote away from 20k!!!!!